# C++ file memory mapping container akin to std::vector / boost::array

Tags: c++, containers, mmap

I was wondering if there is a well C++ library that provides a file memory mapping container akin to std::vector or boost::array, with the notable difference that it operates on a file memory map.

Right now I'm considering implementing such myself, based on boost::array, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [boost interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). It contains a lot of containers and allocators suitable for use with arbirtrary memory locations. There is also direct support for [mapped files](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/interprocess/managed_memory_segments.html#interprocess.managed_memory_segments.managed_mapped_files).

Comment: Thanks. I was just looking into the wrong direction. I'll wait for other answers as well before I accept.